# O docker em laravel seria a mesma coisa que o Laragon?

Tags: laravel, docker

Pessoal estou com uma duvida, sou iniciante em laravel eu estou usando o Laragon como virtual host para abrir o projetos no navegador, porém ouvir falar de um docker eu pesquisei sobre ele e me pareceu ser a mesma coisa que o Laragon mais não tenho certeza alguém sabe se é isso mesmo se os dois forem a mesma coisa qual é o melhor para usar?

```
$this->group(['middleware' => ['auth'], 'namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function(){

    $this->any('historico-search', 'BalanceController@searchHistorico')->name('historico.search');
    $this->get('historico', 'BalanceController@historico')->name('admin.historico');

    $this->post('transfer', 'BalanceController@transferStore')->name('transfer.store');
    $this->post('confirm-transfer', 'BalanceController@confirmTransfer')->name('confirm.transfer');
    $this->get('transfer', 'BalanceController@transfer')->name('balance.transfer');

    $this->post('withdraw', 'BalanceController@withdrawStore')->name('balance.withdraw');
    $this->get('withdraw', 'BalanceController@withdraw')->name('withdraw.store');

    $this->post('deposito', 'BalanceController@depositoStore')->name('deposito.store');
    $this->get('deposito', 'BalanceController@deposito')->name('balance.deposito');
    $this->get('balance', 'BalanceController@index')->name('admin.balance');

    $this->get('/', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin.home');
});
```

Comment: E qual seria a relação deste código de rotas com a sua pergunta?

Comment: Parece que a pergunta é diferente do contexto ... ? faltou algo a explicar?

Answer (score 1):

Os dois são muito diferentes,o  Laragon isola os ambientes de desenvolvimentos enquanto o docker isola recursos do sistema operacional utilizando a base do kernel do SO, por esse motivo o Docker se torna uma tecnologia muito melhor pois:

1 - É independente de qualquer tecnologia, ele pode isolar, desde um Wordpress, a um ERP em python Odoo.

2 -  o que você isola são os processo de tal forma que um processo nem sabe que outro de um outro contêiner existe, semelhante as VM mas não são VMs pois a forma como trabalham usa muito menos recurso de maquina  e na maioria dos casos (todos que eu tive a experiencia de aplicar) melhora o desempenho da aplicação.

3 - Docker veio para resolver o problema de "na minha maquina funciona", isso vai alem do ambiente de desenvolvimento e indo para produção, de modo que a aplicação se comporte da mesma forma sem problema algum independente de onde foi desenvolvido e onde vai ser implementado.

4 - Em questão de tendencia o docker já é realidade do mercado e cada vez mais essa tecnologia em contêiner é mais absorvida, vou deixar linkis de eo sistemas que que correm forte para docker e oferecem serviços

https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/quickstart-docker

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/kubernetes-service/docker/

https://devcenter.heroku.com/categories/deploying-with-docker

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html

https://www.ibm.com/blogs/bluemix/2017/12/introducing-docker-ee-ibm-cloud/

https://marketplace.digitalocean.com/apps/docker